# Emulate System style on custom .NET Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I've derived the ComboBox Class in order to have a custom layout of the list items. This is a DropDown list style Combobox, which has a nice appearance, while the custom one looks like an old-style one.

[image: Custom Combobox vs Default]

Is there any way to emulate or force the control to draw the "windows default-style" layout while still having a custom design? This is, having a style similar to the right one on the picture above, with the gradient background (or whatever it takes depending on the version of windows).

This what I've done so far:

```
    public ComboBoxRGB()
    {
        this.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrawItem(e);

        if (Items.Count > 0)
        {
            if (e.Index > -1)
            {
                if (Items[e.Index] == null) return;

                int BarWidth = 16;
                int BarSpacing = 1;
                int Spacing_Top = 2;
                int Spacing_Left = 3;
                int Spacing_Right = 4;

                ComboBoxRGBItem item;
                try
                {
                    item = (ComboBoxRGBItem)Items[e.Index];
                }
                catch { return; }

                e.DrawBackground();
                e.DrawFocusRectangle();

                //Draw color indicator
                System.Drawing.SolidBrush bColor = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(item.Red, item.Green, item.Blue));
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bColor, Spacing_Left + e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top + Spacing_Top, 12, 12);

                //Draw text
                System.Drawing.SolidBrush sbText = (e.State == System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemState.Selected) ? new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.White) : new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, e.Font, sbText, Spacing_Left + e.Bounds.Left + BarWidth + Spacing_Right, e.Bounds.Top);

            } //IF_Index
        } //IF_Items_Count
    }
```

I would be very pleased if anyone has any idea on how to do this. I would like to try to emulate the appearance manually, since this changes from windows version to version.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find information about this on internet, so I suppose is not possible to auto-draw the backgound using system-default-style.

For the moment, the solution used is to draw it completely manually, through the override of Paint method, but this requires to take into account what is the version of Windows being executed and use different designs for drawing the control.

In case anyone has a different solution or any suggestion, please, let me know it.